# String Type in IIOP.NET?

Tags: .net, corba, iiop

I'm new to IIOP.Net. I have built a simple Adder Corba App using IIOP.Net ( with much help from StackOverFlow community, thanks again).

Now, I'm having a problem with String type in IIOP.Net

I have a remote method that return a String:

```
public String myMethod()
{
    return "This is a String, right?";
}
```

The CLStoIDL generate for me a A.idl file ( where A is my remote object). Then I use IDLtoCLS so compile to .dll file for my C# client.

The problem is my Visual studio seems not to see the class in .dll file. Its apparently that my .dll file has some errors. Then I changed the return type of my method to int,

```
public int myMethod()
{
    return 12345678;
}
```

This time, the .Net client can call the method and get the int value. So I think I have to do much with String type. Look at their doc. I see that, I have to use AttributeUseage, like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.ReturnValue)]
    public sealed class StringValueAttribute: Attribute, IidlAttirebute
{
}
```

But I have no idea how to implement that.

Actually, I have a solution for that is to change the return type of my method to Object, but then, in client, I have to cast it to String type.

Could someone please give me an advice to handle String type?
Thank you.

Comment: Is using Object type instead of String type for method returns String type Ok?

Comment: I aways prefer to make my own IDL without using CLStoIDL. Can you show the idl file?

Comment: @Makah: Thank you for reply but I figured out a new way. Just copy the .dll file that generated by Server project. :)